# Merge MP4 Files and Add Chapters For Each One

Tags: windows, mp4, merge, matroska, chapters

On Windows, I'd like to merge a group of MP4 files and add a chapter marker for each file in the resulting MKV/MP4. Does anyone know how to do this? I've tried using mkvtoolnix but I'm not sure if it's possible with the GUI